# Hibernate join many to many criteria query from SQL

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

I want to implement this Sql query to fetch all the data from both tables using hibernate criteria api. Please help me in writing the code in Dao to fetch all the data from both tables only by using hibernate criteria api.

```
SELECT o.outletId,o.outletName,m.menuId ,m.menuItem,m.menuType 
FROM outlet AS o 
    INNER JOIN outlet_menu_mapping AS om  ON o.outletId = om.menuId
    INNER JOIN menu AS m ON om.outletId = m.menuId 
WHERE m.menuID = 1;
```

This is my MENU persistence class and I want to fetch data from database using many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Menu")
public class Menu  {

      @Id
        @Column(name="menuId")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int menuId;

        @Column(name="menuItem",nullable=false)
        private String menuItem;

        @Column(name="menuType",nullable=false)
        private String menuType;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="menu")
        private Set<Outlet> outlet = new HashSet<Outlet>();

        public int getMenuId() {
            return menuId;
        }

        public void setMenuId(int menuId) {
            this.menuId = menuId;
        }

        public String getMenuItem() {
            return menuItem;
        }

        public void setMenuItem(String menuItem) {
            this.menuItem = menuItem;
        }

        public String getMenuType() {
            return menuType;
        }

        public void setMenuType(String menuType) {
            this.menuType = menuType;
        }




}
```

This is my Outlet persistence class and I want to fetch data from database using many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Outlet")
public class Outlet implements Serializable {

        //private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;
        @Id
        @Column(name="outletId")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int outletId;

        @Column(name="outletName",nullable=false)
        private String Name;

        private Menu menu;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="outlet_menu_mapping", 
                    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="outletId")}, 
                    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="menuId")})
        private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();


        public int getOutletId() {
            return outletId;
        }



        public void setOutletId(int outletId) {
            this.outletId = outletId;
        }



        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }



        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }



        public Menu getMenu() {
            return menu;
        }



        public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
            this.menu = menu;
        }


/*
        @Override
        public String toString() {
               return "Student[outletId=" + outletId + ", Name=" + Name
                 +  "]";
              } */
}
```

This is the criteria which I am trying to implement but it shows errors

```
List outlet = session.createCriteria(Outlet.class).createAlias("Menu", "m").add( Restrictions.eq("m.menuId", "1") ).list();
```

Comment: I am new to hibernate criteria. Please convert many to many relationship using criteria query of this sql statement.

Comment: Please, add your persistent classes. And add additional information to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: List outlet =  session.createCriteria(Outlet.class).createAlias("Menu", "m").add( Restrictions.eq("m.menuId", "1") ).list();

Comment: Outlet doesn't have any field named "Menu". It's named "menu" (and should be named "menus", since it's a collection of seveal menus). Also, menuId is of type int. So it can't be equal to "1", which is of type String.

Comment: @JBNizet Sir, Applied as you informed me. what other changes should i make.

Comment: @v.ladynev Please help.